# How to link two docker services in coreos with flannel?

Tags: docker, coreos, orchestration

I tried to understand, how to perform a simplest task ever - link two containers running on different coreOS hosts, and failed. As from coreos site documentation, I understood how to simply enable flannel service, but how do you start containers linking each other in systemd services?

Can anybody provide some tutorial where there will be clear even for an idiot steps to start two containers in different coreos virtual machines locally, linked together? Like four simple steps:

1. cloud-config (where you enabling flannel)
2. systemd file for first docker service (say redis)
3. systemd file for second docker service (say flask, linking redis)
4. command to start those two up.

thx.